# Write an equation that meets these requirements.

Tags: calculus

1) Removable discontinuity at $x=8$; vertical asymptote at $x=7$.

2) $\lim\limits _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ f\left( x \right)  } =\frac { 2 }{ 9 }$ ; vertical asymptote at $x= -9/4$

3) Hole at $(-4, 2)$

4) Vertical asymptote at $x= 2$; hole at $(6,3)$

Could you please provide a solution to each condition?

Thanks very much

Comment: What do mean by a hole?

Comment: @Marvis Removable discontinuity.

Comment: I am guessing those are supposed to mean removable discontinuity.
I don't know how to make an equation for each requirement though.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to give you a general formula you can use for each of those.

The so called homographic functions, with $ad-cb \neq 0$

$$y=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$

have the following general properties:

$$f(0)=\frac{b}{d}$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to -\frac d c} f(x) = \infty $$
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \frac a c$$

Maybe, a more natural form is the canonical one, where we have

$$y=k+\frac{a}{x-h}$$

The properties are now even more evident,

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = k$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to h} f(x) = \infty $$

and $$f(0)=k-\frac a h $$

Their complex analog, [the Möbius transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), play an important role in complex analysis.

Also, given any continuous function $g(x)$, we can create a removable discontinuity by defining

$$G(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) \text{ ; } x \neq a \cr M \text{ ; } x =a \end{cases}$$

where $M \neq g(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y={\sin x\over x}$$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=0$. Can you figure out how to move it to $x=8$? and then how to tack on a vertical aymptote at $x=7$?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

1. My favorite vertical asymptote comes from $1/x^2$. Do you know how to move the asymptote around?
2. My favorite removable discontinuity is the function $f(x)=0$ for all $x\neq 0$, $f(0)=1$.